# Google Maps API v3 - TypeError: Result of expression 'google.maps.LatLng' [undefined] is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a static html page to display a number of locations from a data. I've just copied one of the samples and are working backwards but I'm getting the following error in the Safari Inspector:

```
main.js:1SyntaxError: Parse error
sample.htm:10TypeError: Result of expression 'google.maps.LatLng' [undefined] is not a constructor.
```

Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Multi Markers Sample via Google Maps</title> 
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.2965590,153.1152650);
var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.2956470,153.1123707);
var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.2864430,153.1360230);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 13,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
map: map,
icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
title:"Original Location"     });   
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng1,
map: map,
title:"Tom Cruise"     }); 
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng2,
map: map,
title:"Lady Gaga"     }); 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body onLoad="initialize()">   
<div id="map_canvas"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here - it actually works in IE v8 on Windows but not in Safari and I need to get it working for both.

Answer (score 22):

Add callback function to your google maps request.
It'll be executed after Google loads everything it needs.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize
```

Comment: brilliant.. +1 really :)

Comment: Read doco or visit StackOverflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

hi please use this code using JQuery
`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Multi Markers Sample via Google Maps</title> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
      <style>
        #map_canvas {
            height: 500px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.2965590, 153.1152650);
        var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.2956470, 153.1123707);
        var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.2864430, 153.1360230);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
            title: "Original Location"
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng1,
            map: map,
            title: "Tom Cruise"
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng2,
            map: map,
            title: "Lady Gaga"
        });
    });
</script> 
</head> 
<body >  
<div id="map_canvas"></div> 
</body> 
</html>`
```